# Is there a shorthand way to denullify a string in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, null

Is there a shorthand way to denullify a string in C#?

It would be the equivalent of (if 'x' is a string):

```
string y = x == null ? "" : x;
```

I guess I'm hoping there's some operator that would work something like:

```
string y = #x;
```

Wishful thinking, huh?

The closest I've got so far is an extension method on the string class:

```
public static string ToNotNull(this string value)
{
    return value == null ? "" : value;
}
```

which allows me to do:

```
string y = x.ToNotNull();
```

Any improvements on that, anyone?

Comment: I avoid null strings to avoid this problem. If someone else is creating the null strings, violence might be necessary. YMMV.

Comment: The fact that your last example works is quite scary, since your calling a method on an object to check whether the object is = null. I know its due to extension methods being static but it kinda feels wrong when looking at it.

Comment: null strings are evil, instantiate with String.Empty and avoid logic as above.

Comment: Blame out-of-the-box LINQ to SQL data classes for null strings.  That's what I get if the columns are nullable.  I just want to turn them into something consistent.  I quite like my ToNotNull().  I think I might change it to ToDbNice() and do the trimming of chars/nchars at the same time.

Comment: Expected for a next version of C#: [nullable reference types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/15/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will work:

```
string y = x ?? "";
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you need this reguarly, instead of an extension method you might want to consider creating your own type which behaves like a Nullable and shares the same usage as there is a System.Nullable.GetValueOrDefault(); method. Unfortunately, you can only use System.Nullable on value types so you can't make a nullable string as standard.